# Installing Debian package error: trying to overwrite '/bin/cpio', which is also in package cpio

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install National instruments NIVISA on Ubuntu 18.04 and I get an error

```
trying to overwrite '/bin/cpio', which is also in package cpio 2.12+dfsg-6
```

I have tried to remove the CPIO package

```
user@user:~/NI-2015/nivisa$ sudo dpkg -P cpio
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of cpio:
 ubuntu-standard depends on cpio.
 initramfs-tools-core depends on cpio.
 alien depends on cpio.
```

This NI-VISA installation wants to install a library I already have. How can I ignore the installation of CPIO and move on?